# Как сделать волнистую полоску на css?

Tags: css, css3

Подскажите, как можно сделать вот такую полоску лесенкой с помощью `css`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

На `html` и `css`

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
.angles{
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0 0 0 10px;
}
.angles li{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border:4px solid yellow;
  border-left:none;
  border-bottom:none;
  transform:rotate(-37deg) skewX(14deg);
  transform-origin:center;
  margin-right:14px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="angles">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

На `svg`

```css
#angles{
  stroke-width:3px;
  stroke:yellow;
  fill:none;
}
```

```html
<svg width="142px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 142 16" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice">
  <path id="angles" d="M0,2 l15.778,13 15.778,-13 15.778,13 15.778,-13 15.778,13 15.778,-13  15.778,13 15.778,-13 15.778,13" />
</svg>
```

Comment: У углов градус не тот (впрочем, в svg-версии ближе к «тому»)

Comment: @andreymal , согласен. Угол там больше прямого. Исправил.

Comment: @Геннадий Журов а как подобрать полоску размером 142 на 16 и 4,5 зубьев, как в примере? ниже есть рещение, но там на белом фоне. вот если бы прозрачный - было бы идеально!

Comment: @Вася , обновил svg-вариант

Answer (score 7):

```css
body {
    background: green;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none
}

.a::before {
        padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background: yellow;
    width: 17px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transform: rotate(-20deg)
}

.a::after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    content: "";
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
        left: 15px;

    display: block;
    background: yellow;
    width: 17px;
    height: 2px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    transform: rotate(20deg)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
      <li class="a"></li>
      <li class="a"></li>
      <li class="a"></li>
      <li class="a"></li>
      <li class="a"></li>
      <li class="a"></li>
  </ul>   
</body>
</html>
```

Если угол наклона линий захотите поменять.

Comment: При попытке сделать их более толстыми (как на картинке автора) у меня начало выходить что попало https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbrKT.png

Comment: @andreymal надо margin-right подогнать

Answer (score 5):

Конечно, не помешало бы сглаживание, но можно с помощью `linear-gradient`:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ffd800;
  background-size: 32px 20px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0, -16px 0, 16px 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(35deg, #fff 11px, transparent 0), linear-gradient(-35deg, #fff 11px, transparent 0), linear-gradient(-145deg, #fff 11px, transparent 0), linear-gradient(145deg, #fff 11px, transparent 0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

*P.S. Если угол `45deg` то артефактов нет.*

Comment: благодарю! Если ограничить ширину и высоту, то получается то, что нужно

Comment: но это годится только для белого фона? или можно сделать на прозрачном тоже?

Comment: В моем случае только с белым фоном. То есть тут фон на самом то деле желтый, а с помощью наложения белых треугольников получается рисунок.